# redmine sub-url on apache2 debian

Tags: debian, apache2, redmine

I had instaled Redmine under Debian8 and Apache/2.4.10 (Debian), it works great. The default instalation causes, it is only app served by Apache...
After mamy googling links and hints, I try change it with Apache configuration in way described here:

basic Redmine file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf`) is:

```
# The passenger module (from the libapache2-mod-passenger package) must be
# enabled
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ServerName my.domain.name
    # this is the passenger config eee
    RailsEnv production
    SetEnv X_DEBIAN_SITEID "default"
    # CHANGE PassengerAppGroupName FOR OTHER INSTANCES
    PassengerAppGroupName redmine_default
    PassengerDefaultUser www-data
    Alias "/plugin_assets/" /var/cache/redmine/default/plugin_assets/
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public
    <Directory "/usr/share/redmine/public">
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

so, I try to move this settings a little bit upper - from sites-available to conf-available (similar like phpMyAdmin), and created `/etc/apache2/conf-available/redmine.conf` :

```
Alias /redmine /usr/share/redmine/public/

PassengerDefaultUser www-data
DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public

<Location /redmine>
    RailsEnv production
    SetEnv X_DEBIAN_SITEID "default"
    # CHANGE PassengerAppGroupName FOR OTHER INSTANCES
    PassengerAppGroupName redmine_default

</Location>
Alias "/redmine/plugin_assets/" /var/cache/redmine/default/plugin_assets/

<Directory "/usr/share/redmine/public/">
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and I added:

```
RedmineApp::Application.routes.default_scope = "/redmine"
```

to file: `/usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb` 
(according to hint in: `http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI` )

...and :-( 
now Redmine works with 'localhost/redmine'
but eg. phpMyAdmin doesnt work and behave like bad redmine-link

When I remove `DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public` line from `redmine.conf` - all works except redmine... link `localhost/redmine` show:

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /redmine/ on this server.**

and Apache error.log :

```
[Sun Nov 12 14:14:52.162868 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 12220] [client ::1:45382] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /usr/share/redmine/public/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml ...
```

My question is: is there a way to use `DocumentRoot` depending on match Alias? Or maybe is another way to fix it...

EDIT:

when `redmine.conf` is changed to:

```
[...]
#DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public
[...]
<Directory "/usr/share/redmine/public/">

        PassengerEnabled on
        SetHandler none
        PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/redmine
        RailsBaseURI /redmine/redmine

        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And, at the end of file `environment.rb` , I have added:

```
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

Now it works (Redmine and phpMyAdmin and other php) perfect!

:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Passenger, the proper value to pass if your app is in sub-folder is:

```
PassengerBaseURI /redmine
```

From their website, just replace subapp with redmine...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.phusion.nl
    DocumentRoot /websites/phusion/public
    <Directory /websites/phusion>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # These have been added:
    Alias /subapp /websites/secondapp/public
    <Location /subapp>
        PassengerBaseURI /subapp
        PassengerAppRoot /websites/secondapp

    </Location>
    <Directory /websites/secondapp/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Complete integration guide is:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/